# How to display HTML content in a textblock

Tags: c#, html, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am Working on `Windows Phone 8 application`, i have a xml in which one of the tage contains data as below:

```
<text><![CDATA[Identify the following sentence. 
<I>King of Forest is Lion.</I>]]></text>
```

I have a textblock which is displaying this:

Output: `<I>King of Forest is Lion.</I>`

But the entire text which is with  tag should be shown in italics.how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) will help you for what are you looking for.